# Why is my *ngIf detecting an object is not empty (Angular2)?

Tags: angular

In `my.component.ts`, I have this part in my template

```
<li><a *ngIf="m_userO=={}" [routerLink]="['LoginPage']">Login</a></li>
<li><a *ngIf="m_userO!={}" (click)="logOut(m_userO)">{{m_userO.first_name}}<br>Logout</a></li>
```

and I export

```
export class myComponent{
m_userO : userO = {};
}
```

In the `loginPage.component.ts`, I import `myComponent` and when they press login, this happens

```
myComponent.m_userO = this.x_userO;
```

where I've confirmed `x_userO` is not empty at this point.

The idea is that if they're not logged in, it will say "Login" and if they are, it will say "Logout". The problem is when I load the website, it's already showing "Logout" but I'm not sure why. Thanks.

Comment: You can't compare objects with `==`. You can check it. Define `var a = {}` and `var b = {}` and check `(a == b)` or `(a === b)` none returns true.
As Reginaldo suggested is better for you to use null or undefined in order to determine if the value hasn't been set.

Answer (score 2):

Try let the instance undefined or null if the user isn't logged and then when he logges create the instance. After this compare the instances like this:

```
<li><a *ngIf="m_userO" [routerLink]="['LoginPage']">Login</a></li>
<li><a *ngIf="!m_userO" (click)="logOut(m_userO)">{{m_userO.first_name}}<br>Logout</a></li>
```